# POX: connection reset after first connection

Tags: python, networking, mininet, openflow, sdn

Firstly i am new to python!. Lately i am facing some issues in my code.This is my code for installing two flow rules into multiple switches:

```
    import inspect
    from pox.core import core
    import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of
    from pox.lib.revent import *
    from pox.lib.util import dpidToStr
    from pox.lib.addresses import EthAddr, IPAddr
    import pox.lib.packet as pkt
    from collections import namedtuple
    import os
    import csv
    from csv import DictReader
    import time

    log = core.getLogger()
    FirewallPolicies = "%s/pox/pox/misc/firewall-policies.csv" % os.environ[ 'HOME' ]

    class CustomFirewall (EventMixin):

    def __init__ (self):
    self.listenTo(core.openflow)
    log.debug("Enabling Firewall Module")

    def _handle_ConnectionUp (self, event):
    ''' Add your logic here ... '''
    ReadFile = open(FirewallPolicies, 'r')
    ReaderFile = csv.DictReader(ReadFile)
    Deny = {}
    for row in ReaderFile:
            Deny[row['id']] = ({'mac_0':row['mac_0'],'mac_1':row['mac_1']})
    log.debug("Deny table - %s",Deny)
    for x in Deny.values():
            log.debug("Source Mac is %s",x['mac_0'])
            log.debug("Destination Mac is %s",x['mac_1'])
            log.debug("1")
            match = of.ofp_match(dl_src = x['mac_0'], dl_dst = x['mac_1'])
            log.debug("2")
            fm = of.ofp_flow_mod()
            fm.priority = 20
            fm.match = match
            event.connection.send(fm)
            log.debug("Firewall rules installed on %s", dpidToStr(event.dpid))

    def launch ():
    '''
    Starting the Firewall module
    '''
    log.debug("Jyoti's Custom firewall launched")
    core.registerNew(CustomFirewall)
```

Issue: 
I am able to install first rule into the switch but not able to install second rule.

Error messages:
DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Source Mac is 00:00:00:00:00:01

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Destination Mac is 00:00:00:00:00:02

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:1

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:2

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Firewall rules installed on 00-00-00-00-00-09 -> **First rule is installed**

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Source Mac is 00:00:00:00:00:04

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Destination Mac is 00:00:00:00:00:03

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:1

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:2

DEBUG:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-09 33] Socket error: Connection reset by peer -> **Second rule fails to install**

INFO:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-09 33] disconnected

DEBUG:misc.Custom_firewall_2:Firewall rules installed on 00-00-00-00-00-09

ERROR:openflow.of_01:[00-00-00-00-00-0f 37] OpenFlow

Error: [00-00-00-00-00-0f 37]

Error: header: [00-00-00-00-00-0f 37]

Error: version: 1 [00-00-00-00-00-0f 37]

Error: type: 1 (OFPT_ERROR)

...

...

... so on

NOTE:

if i use self.connection.send(fm) i get :

```
    self.connection.send(fm)
    AttributeError: 'CustomFirewall' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

if i use event.connection.send(fm) i get connection reset issue

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Did the answer helped ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any actions for the flow. So I assume you want to drop those packets right?

Try to put something like this

```
packet = event.parsed
msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
msg.match = of.ofp_match.from_packet(packet)
msg.idle_timeout = 10
msg.hard_timeout = 30
msg.buffer_id = event.ofp.buffer_id
msg.data = event.ofp # 6a
event.connection.send(fm)
```

in the body of for loop. Just to see if you can add any flow to the switches(i.e. not use the Deny class).

> I recommend to use Ryu instead of pox. POX only supports OF1.0 while RYU supports till 1.4 and has better documentation.